# How to avoid constantly changing the default parameters in the yml header of rmarkdown documents for debugging in RStudio?

Tags: git, r-markdown, rstudio

Using RStudio, I am developing markdown documents that are used to generate HTML reports for a large set of parameters. During development I routinely change parameters defined in the yml header of the `.Rmd` file to debug a certain set of parameters. However, I do not want to commit these frequent and irrelevant changes to git, so I currently always add my changes interactively (`git add -p`) to exclude these changes. However, this is quite time consuming an error prone.

Is there a good way to change the parameters of a rmarkdown document for debugging purposes without changing the source but with still being able to "Restart R and run all chunks" in RStudio?

Comment: Try [clean/smudge filters](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitattributes%5D+filters) approach. A clean filter should remove parameters from the files or replace them with something standard. A smudge filter should restore parameters from… well, probably from an ignored, non-tracked file.